# How to loop through the folder and files in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a folder let say (Main folder), which could have sub folders based on the employee id ex ( 67,68,78,92.. etc) which means that employee 67,68, 78 and 92 has uploaded some excel files to their folder. How can I loop through all sub folders and their files one by one.

In the beginning, I have only main folder. I am not aware that which employee is going to upload how many excel sheet for a particular month.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the "Foreach Loop Container". When you double-click it, go to "Collection" and choose the "Foreach File Enumerator". Once you do that, it will ask for the folder that contains the files, here you have to choose your Main folder. Then you need to check the "Traverse subfolders" checkbox and that should do it.

[Looping over files with the Foreach Loop](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx)